# JavaScript error on moderator dashboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

On the moderator dashboard (`/admin`), there is some (new?) JavaScript defined inline-in-the-page;

```js
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'name',
    is: function(s) { return false; },
    format: function(s) { return $(s).find('a').text().toUpperCase(); },
    type: 'text'
});
```

However, this snippet of JavaScript (specifically, the "format" function) causes a...

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Absence recorded at: Jan 01 at 00:00;

... when there is a mod recorded as absent (I've obfuscated the above date).

This leaves the other JavaScript functionality (e.g. top-nav) broken once the page loads.

Comment: Can't reproduce, can you share your password? ;)

Comment: jQuery’s overloading is fine and good.

Comment: Sounds like the moderator dashboard needs more jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-fix suppressing the errors from absentee notice rows, to prevent the rest of the page from being broken, will be included in the next build.

The sorter still won't handle the absentee notice rows very intelligently: they'll be sorted to the bottom instead of grouped with their corresponding moderator information rows. I'd like to fix that when I have a chance, but at least it's isolated to a single table instead of breaking the entire page.